# Developer.here.com API hangs on request

Tags: javascript, json, api

I just looked for a webservice which returns isochrones of travel times for a given map and starting point and found this code example which seems to do what I want:

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/example-isoline-simple-time.html

However I don't have any idea of how to use this. I googled but didn't find anything helpful. I created a free plan from https://developer.here.com/ to get an app_id and an app_code. I just used them to create a one line string from the example code below and copied it to the url line of my browser, but it didn't display anything it just says that it is waiting for the server.

```
https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
&rangetype=time
&start=geo!52.51578,13.37749
&range=300
```

So what would be the correct way to make this example work (from linux if this matters).

**Edit**

Here are the app_id and app_code of my test app:

[image: Test_Data]

Then I just copied the following string to my url-bar:

```
https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?app_id={dvCtO8JoOhmzZGqOaNve}&app_code={N4p8QokLC5D1xYf_rk3z5g}&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&rangetype=time&start=geo!52.51578,13.37749&range=300
```

Anything wrong with this?

**Edit 2**

In firefox this just hangs and gives afters some minutes a "Secure connection failed" error. I also tried it with chromium-browser which results in the following error message:

```
{"response":{"_type":"ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType","type":"PermissionError","subtype":"InvalidCredentials","details":"This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair. Please verify that the values are not swapped between the app_id and app_code and the values provisioned by HERE (either by your customer representative or via http://developer.here.com/myapps) were copied correctly into the request.","metaInfo":{"timestamp":"2016-08-10T11:03:37Z","mapVersion":"8.30.62.159","moduleVersion":"7.2.71.0-39010","interfaceVersion":"2.6.25"}}}
```

Comment: don't see anything related to making a json request. Maybe change the topic to something more relevant, e.g. "developer.here.com API hangs on request"

Comment: @Yerken: The problem was that I didn't know how to try this example (I am not a developer), since I didn't find anything by googling around, I made an educated guess that is might work when I just copy the whole line to the url bar (since I have seen urls with similar schemes when surfing the web). However your comment indicates that this was indeed the correct method to do this, right?

Comment: yes u need to replace {YOUR_APP_ID} and {YOUR_APP_CODE} with real app_id and app_code and copy paste the url into the browser url bar, if it still doesn't work without giving meaningful response blame the service :O

Comment: @yerken Thanks. On the service web site they say: ask on stackoverflow :-). So I have some more details above and changed the title as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

But not work a error 405 (Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405), and true... i not know auth ur web api. Look a example code is try.

**Example code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var app_id = "dvCtO8JoOhmzZGqOaNve";
 var app_code = "N4p8QokLC5D1xYf_rk3z5g";
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json", 
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+btoa(app_id+":"+app_code)); 
  },
  data: [{
   "mode":"fastest;car;traffic:disabled",
   "rangetype":"time",
   "start":"geo!52.51578,13.37749",
   "range":"300"
  }]
  /*
        mode:"fastest;car;traffic:disabled",
  rangetype:"time",
  start:"geo!52.51578,13.37749",
  range:"300"/*,
  success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  }*/
 }, function (data) { console.log(data); });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I run your code snippet with the button from your answer, it hangs in firefox and does nothing in chromium-browser

Comment: Code´s correct, but i said not support ur API. Try use application call `Postman`